# RC Filter at the ADC input pins of beagle bone black

Tags: filtering, adc, beagleboneblack

I am trying to read a thermistor with the beagle bone black.

I have a voltage divider circuit that feeds a unity gain Opamp. The O/P of the opamp is connected to a simple RC Low pass filter that feeds voltage to the ADC pin.

The problem I have noticed is that the voltage sensed by the beagle bone is always 0.02V higher than the actual voltage at the opamp output.

At first I thought this was a software issue, but on further investigation I found out that the voltage at the ADC pin is actually raised by 0.02V. If I feed the ADC pin directly from the opamp, without the RC filter I do not have this issue. 
Has anyone else experienced anything similar?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The resistance in the RC filter is too high which is causing a voltage drop because of the internal impedance of the ADC pin.  You can use an active low pass filter to resolve this problem:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter#Active_electronic_realization